# Intermediate code generated in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, intermediate-language

As why Intermediate code is needed is described in [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445553/why-compiling-into-intermediate-code),my question is that,

Is the intermediate code saved in the solution ?

How can I view the whole IL generated ?

[image]

Reflector and the File Disassembler add-in from Denis Bauer. It actually produces source projects from assemblies, where Reflector on its own only displays the disassembled **source** and not Intermediate Code.

Comment: @Paddy thanks for your time..but that post dont say anything about Inter-Code

Comment: Yes, it does. It's called "intermediate language" (or IL) in the .NET world. All common decompilers can show IL, like [Reflector](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2009/07/31/net-reflector-support-can-i-view-disassembled-il-instead-of-decompiled-source-code/), [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler/faq.aspx), [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

Comment: Voting to reopen - the OP is asking if the intermediate code saved in the solution. The "duplicate" does not answer that.

Comment: When  you compile (such as by clicking F5) - an `exe` file is created in the `bin` folder - that file is "written" in IL. As for how to see it - that part is covered in the "duplicate" - by using tools such as mentioned in CodeCoaster's comment above.

Comment: then what about object code !

Comment: You mean real "native code"? - when you click the exe file - the native code is created on the fly. - You don't actually get a file like that in your solution.

Comment: (The `bin` folder I referred to above is inside your solution folder.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile (such as by clicking F5) - an exe file is created in the bin folder inside your solution - that file is "written" in IL. As for how to see it - that part is covered in the "duplicate" - by using tools such as mentioned in CodeCoaster's comment above. (In ILSpy you'll have to choose `IL`instead of `C#` or `VB` to show you the IL.)

Answer (score 1):

To view IL code you should use additional tools like Reflector or ILASM/ILDASM.

It's not saved, it's generated during build.

Comment: _"It's not saved"_ - it is, in the binaries the compiler produces. See [Wiki: Assembly (CLI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29).

Comment: @CodeCaster, see questions - "Is the intermediate code saved in the solution ?",  It's not, it's the output of the build.

Comment: Do you know what OP means by "in the solution"? The output folder usually is inside the solution folder, so in a way, the binaries are in the solution. IL is anyway _not_ "generated in run-time", unless you mean during the runtime of the compiler.

Comment: I don't see anything about folder in question.  Solution is visual studio solution, a output binaries are not included into VS solution.